# Incompatible types conversion using SWIG

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a C++ library that I am trying to use under Java. To mimic it well I am trying to use `typedefs` in the interface `.i` SWIG file. I am having hard time converting generic types to Java. So far I have such code in the `.i` interface file:

```
%module api
%{
    #include "api.h"

    typedef unsigned __int64 Tint64u;
    typedef Tint64u TContext_t;
%}
%include "api.h"

%apply unsigned long long { unsigned __int64 };

typedef unsigned __int64 Tint64u;
typedef Tint64u TContext_t;
```

and under my C++ class I have such class where one of the methods take `TContext_t` as an input argument:

```
class APIClass {

public:
    APIClass();
    void test(TContext_t context);

};
```

I compiled it with SWIG and under Java I am trying to use this method like so:

```
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("api");
        APIClass api = new APIClass();
        api.test((SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned___int64) BigInteger.valueOf(0));
    }
}
```

But here I am getting an error that `BigInteger cannot be converted to SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned___int64`. What am I missing in my interface file so that I could start passing numeric values into my `test()` method? I would like to initialize it with 0 for starters, later it is going to be filled in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You've got things in the wrong order here. When SWIG sees your header file via the `%include` directive it has no idea what a `TContext_t` actually is. This is because it handles each thing line by line. So it ends up making something up as it goes along, which is almost always not what you want. You can  spot that here because the typename in the method it generates starts with `SWIGTYPE_`.

The fix should be simple though. If you change the ordering of your .i file to be like this:

```
%module api
%{
    #include "api.h"

    typedef unsigned __int64 Tint64u;
    typedef Tint64u TContext_t;
%}
%apply unsigned long long { unsigned __int64 };

typedef unsigned __int64 Tint64u;
typedef Tint64u TContext_t;

%include "api.h"
```

Then it should just work, provided you also remove the incorrect cast from your call in the Java example..